# How to check the pmd results in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pmd

Have a Java project and just automated it's build process using Jenkins Here is my console output of Jenkin console

```
18:50:22 Started by user suresh
18:50:22 Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\pmdtest
18:50:23 [PMD] Collecting PMD analysis files...
18:50:23 [PMD] Finding all files that match the pattern **/pmd.xml
18:50:23 [PMD] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #6
18:50:23 Finished: SUCCESS
```

I can see that there are messages related to PMD.

May be I need to give something in the below configuration ? above output is when the below box (in image) is empty. Want to PMD all the js files. So tried

[image]

However, I do not know how to check the generated report? Is there any location that I have to go and check the results ?

What exactly needs to give there? May be that solves the other problem ?

Comment: Have you installed the [PMD plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PMD+Plugin)?

Answer (score 1):

The Jenkins PMD Plugin doesn't do any analysis, this must be done by the [maven pmd plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/index.html). The Jenkins plugin can just display the results.

Try to add the goal `pmd:pmd` to your maven command, this will generate a result file `target/pmd.xml` which you need to add to the config (PMD results).